# JQ - How to concat two arrays, one from request with local json one

Tags: json, bash, curl, jq

I have some curl get, receiving array from it. At the same time I have some local json file with some data already saved. I need to combine those. My way which returns error (`curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 2712`):

```
curl GET -G 'url' | jq --argjson arr1 '[.articles[] | {
    title: .title,
    description: .description,
    author: .author,
    content: .content
}]' --argjson arr2 'seeds.json' -n '$arr1 + $arr2 | group_by(.title) | map(.[-1])' > seeds.json
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Please follow the [mcve] guidelines as much as possible. In the present instance, you could show a relevant subset of the output of `curl` together with (a possibly shortened version of) seeds.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your invocation of jq is a bit of a jumble.  You should aim for something like the following:

```
curl GET -G 'url' |
    jq --argfile arr2 seeds.json '
       [.articles[] 
        | { title, description, author, content}] as $arr1
       | $arr1 + $arr2
       | group_by(.title) 
       | map(.[-1])'
```

Notice that the construction of the JSON object in $arr1 has been greatly simplified.